# VB.NET Win. Form - Showing a custom control outside of the container control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox, user-controls, containers

I have a created a custom user control which consists of 2 controls:-

1. Textbox
2. Listbox

The function of this control is to act as a dropdown list. Below is the image of the control:-

[image]

### Problem

Now the problem i am facing is that if i insert this ***user control*** into a container control like a panel then the list gets hidden inside that container control.

[image]

and if i just create the user control outside the container control then it would interfere with the Tab Order (focus order) of the form.

***Is there any work around where the user control exists in the container control and still shows the complete list without being hidden in the panel?***

**Edit** i wrongly added **c#** instead of **VB.NET**

Comment: Have you tried with `meListControl.BringToFront();` ?

Comment: @m.rogalski yes it is already implemented in the code but the list still gets hidden because of the container control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a C# Winforms Control that hovers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353561/how-to-create-a-c-sharp-winforms-control-that-hovers) - Perhaps consider extending the stock ComboBox which implements this functionality out of the box.

Comment: Try with this WinAPI call : [`SetWindowPos(meListControl.Handle(), HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0,  0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @m.rogalski can you please tell how to implement it in vb.net, i am new to VB.net.

Comment: @Agent_Spock When I was writing this comment it was tagged with C#... You can check [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowPos.html) for definition.

Comment: @m.rogalski yeah i had a look into it but couldn't find  what is `SWP_SHOWWINDOW`

Comment: @Agent_Spock From the documentation it says ( `SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040` ). Just look at the links I've posted.

Comment: @m.rogalski i tried it but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by having the list as ToolStripDropDown. Similar customization have been done in the following discussion,

[Show control inside user control outside the boundaries of its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199235/show-control-inside-user-control-outside-the-boundaries-of-its-parent)

Hope this suits you.